# PlayFramework instantiate object in current request scope?

Tags: scala, web, playframework-2.1

I am currently active PlayFramework learner who came from world of PHP.

For example I have a Head block object in my app, which should hold title, charset encoding, meta information, etc. Something similar to Magento blocks, but without XML declaration

```
package blocks.Page

object Head {
  var title: String = "";
}
```

In Application.index() method I have

```
blocks.Page.Head.title
Ok(views.html.application.index());
```

And finally in html template

```
@import blocks.Page.Head
<title>@Head.title</title>
```

However, blocks.Page.Head object is defined for entire application scope, not for single request. This object is the same for each request.

**What is the right way to do, what I am trying to do?** I can create container with all blocks and instantiate it with each request, then just pass to all templates. But I have a feeling that this is wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use usual class instead of object and pass instance to template as parameter.

Like this:

```
package blocks.Page

case class Head(title: String = "")
```

Controller:

```
val head = Head("Blah")
Ok(views.html.application.index(head))
```

And template will looks like:

```
@(head: blocks.Page.Head)

...
<title>@head.title</title>
```

Comment: The problem is that I might have couple dozens of such blocks. I don't want to have a that much parameters to pass.

Comment: Obviously I can create some Object which will act as a blocks holder, however I believe that people already solved this problem.

Comment: Play is very simple framework, so there is no any magic way to pass and hold parameters for page. Also you may try to use implicit parameters to simplify your calls

Comment: How people do this then? On your page you can have a lot of blocks. People just pass implicit parameters? I cannot find any info how people do it. Even more I don't know what to search.

Answer (score 0):

I know the feeling when coming from a request-oriented language like PHP :). However, consider application-wide access as a gift of a VM (in PHP we need to go the extra mile of using some bytecode and data caching tool like APC or eAccellerator).

I would probably create a blockManager class which gives you static access to blocks by name/tag/id from the template: `Block.get("MyBlock")`. Then you can define and later modify your caching / storing strategy (holding in memory vs. loading from storage) without affecting your templates.